# Where to put frontend javascript configuration variables

Tags: javascript, node.js, ssl, package, config

I have a Javascript frontend that does Ajax calls to my backend. To do that, it needs a "backend_URL" that I hard-coded in the Ajax get() call, say "http://myservice/backend".

Now if I want to deploy my app on different machines, some of which will use this url with HTTPS: "https://myservice/backend", and some not (because they lack a proper certificate and do not expose valuable data).

Where should I put the "USE_HTTPS=1" config variable so that someone deploying the app can choose to use or not SSL ? Of course the question extends itself to other config variables.

I thought about adding a ".config" file at the project root, but then I don't know how to import it in my code. Or should I export environment variables ? Or a node.js feature ?

Comment: It's the **client-side** code that needs to know this, right?

Comment: Create a file config.js and write your client side config. in it. Import it at header before the file which read config. info.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Yes, the client-side. The server-side has Apache configured to receive either HTTP or HTTPS, but the client does not know about it, so it needs a hint.

Comment: @Mohammed Raja You mean I place it at the root of the project, and add it to <head></head> of my index.html ?

Comment: Check my comments in code section

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I ended up writing a *conf.js* file with content

```
window.CONFIG = {
    SOME_CONSTANT: 22,
}
```

and included it in a new `<script>` in my *index.html* before the other scripts.
The `window` is not mandatory but shows where it comes from when I call that as `window.CONFIG` anywhere in the rest of the javascript.

Comment: Should probably be "SOME_CONSTANT: 22" instead of "SOME_CONSTANT = 22"

Answer (score 2):

```
CONFIG = (function(){  
var conf_info = {};
conf_info["url"] = 'http://codepen.io/pen/';
return{    
  getValue : function(param){
    return conf_info[param];
  }
}
})();

//some where in different file
document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = CONFIG.getValue('url');
```

Comment: That helps, but it is still far from a readable config file (like a grunt/gulp config or a json for instance, without code semantics). If I ask people to edit code, they are not going to like it. Should I read a json from that code ?